# YouTube Data API Queries Per Day Reached?

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I noticed that my site based around the YouTube Data API v3 does not seem to function correctly. When i visit this URL:

https://www.googleapis.com

It says "Not Found" which is the error i am getting when using my site to get data from Youtube. It seems to be blocking me. Also when i run some php scripts that used to work fine using my API key it just gives nothing back.

Looking on the API Manager dashboard > Quotas page it seems the blue bar is max for yesterday and says there was over 1,000,000 queries.

According to Adsense it should be fine for though for requests as it tells me over the last month i have had:

Page Views 4,534
Impressions 8,232 
Clicks 47

[image]

The quota screen:

[image]

It just doesn't seem to add up because they say there is 1,000,000 queries on certain days yet there are only 8,232 Impressions over the whole month.

In my PHP code there are 4 functions that get various data, i had thought about merging them before to make less calls but has assumed it would be fine due to not having much traffic yet.

What can i do about this to get my site working again?

Could it be that somehow someone else got hold of my API key and would changing it reset my quota? I am guessing that perhaps search engines are crawling the pages and it is making a lot of requests though.

On a good day recently the site in question had 470 users and if all 4 functions and a few pages loaded were called that would be 1,880 to 18,800 api calls per day if they looked at 10 pages each (Usually not the case).

So some possible maths:

470 (Users) * 4 (On page API calls) = 1,880 (API Calls)

1,880 (API Calls) * 10 (Page Loads) * 30 (Days) = 564,000 (API Calls Per Month)

Yet google claims i make 1 million queries per day when i don't in a whole month?

I would now at this point try to make more use of cache to save certain data, minimize the requests etc but i am now blocked off from the service and it returns nothing back so i even test or set this up.

Edit -

I was told that someone might have been using curl with proxies since it was a public tool, if they did and used up a high amount of queries this might of got me blocked from the API service.

I don't know if this is the case however but if analytics/adsense does not log that hidden traffic it could explain how it reached max quota so quickly.

Comment: Were you able to visit https://www.googleapis.com before? I think it's a library not a URL you can visit. Anyway try requesting additional quota if you've exceeded your limit [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas#additional_quota).

Comment: Thanks, but if they require billing account and $300 pays for 2 months then the amount from adsense i was getting for the 47 clicks wouldn't even cover the cost and it would be all loss. The thing is my project is small and i don't think the query stats match the usage.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, check the [Quota Calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) to give you an idea with regard to your quota usage. You can see in the quota calculator that each REST call has a quota cost. It's not 1,000,000 "queries", it's 1,000,000 "units". So if you have 500,000 queries which costs 3 quota cost each, that's already 1,500,000 units which exceeds the 1M limit.

Comment: Thanks but now im thinking it has to be the wrong stats though because the only project using the API had it's key changed yesterday. Google tells me i made 300k requests today which is not right at all since there has not even been 1 made.

Answer (score 2):

One answer could be if it was not someone using my API key or hitting my site like crazy with Curl that is not logged somehow then it was actually google bot itself.

Today i reached max quota again and was cut off around 5 so i could have had 7 more hours of traffic before the quota reset. I have now made a logging system, today's data was the following amount of times the API was used:

```
23,502 (Google Bot)
9,572 (Yandex Bot)
1,732 (Normal Traffic)
```

The odd thing other than the fact it's not 1 million total request is i only have 15k pages indexed by google yet over the last month there has been far more requests from google bot.

Answer) So it seems to be that it's actually google itself either giving the wrong stats or just counting it's own bot requests as API queries then blocking me off for allowing them to search through my site which seems really unfair.

So new questions would be:

1) Why exactly are google counting there own bots as queries?

They should exclude there own IP's from API requests, it seems like a way to get people paying $300 when they shouldn't have to since they would never hit quota limits if not for google bots.

2) How is it possible to avoid having your IP logged with PHP if it's not googlebot?

If it is somehow possible then this could be the case but as far as i know people always require a IP and useragent etc to make http requests. I am thinking if it was curl then there would be 23k requests from regular users instead.

3) Also why do google now ask people to post on stackoverflow for support if they don't even respond to questions here?